# The problem of variables not working in the nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, variables, nested, command

`your text`Hello
`your text`I have a folder that contains a series of files. The file inside is added every day
`your text`Now, I wanted to write a command that every time I run it, it will check the files in this folder `your text`one by one and transfer the files whose creation date has been over 2 months to another folder.
`your text`Thank you for your guidance

`your text`set ta=%date%
`your text`set mah_now=%date:~4,2%
`your text`set src=d:\sour_folder
`your text`set dest=d:\des_folder
`your text`for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%a in ('dir %src%  /a:-d /o:d /t:c') do (
`your text`if "%%~c" NEQ "bytes" (
`your text`@echo file name:     %%~d
`your text`@echo creation date: %%~a
`your text`for /f " tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%j in ("%%a") do (
`your text`set /a taf_mah=%mah_now% - %%~j
`your text`if %taf_mah% GTR 2 (
`your text`move %src%%%~d %dest%
`your text`)
`your text`)
`your text`)
`your text`)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set ta=%date%
set mah_now=%date:~4,2%
set src=d:\sour_folder
set dest=d:\des_folder
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%a in ('dir %src%  /a:-d /o:d /t:c') do (
    if "%%~c" NEQ "bytes" (
        @echo file name:     %%~d
        @echo creation date: %%~a
            for /f " tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%j in ("%%a") do (
                set /a taf_mah=%mah_now% - %%~j
                if %taf_mah% GTR 2 (
                    move %src%\%%~d %dest%
                )       
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a folder that contains a series of files. The file inside is added every day
Now, I wanted to write a command that every time I run it, it will check the files in this folder one by one and transfer the files whose creation date has been over 2 months to another folder.
The commands I wrote are below, but they don't work
Thank you for your guidance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).